# Rearrange words in java

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I am trying to do a word replace tool to reduce google translate gibberish.

What i need to do right now is:
i have a String like : lalala text lalatxt.
and i need to convert it to look like : lalala texttxt lalala.

Basically some characters show up at the end of wrong words and i want to put them back where they are supposed to be.

I am new to regular expressions and i tried looking at the documentation but cant seem to find what i need.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

edit: the text i am using for input is in korean ( I dont speak korean so i dont know the system they use for writing very well). i wanna address situations like this:
"after adding some spaces, i found that pagoesul pieces translates to destruction sculpting, while doing that, i figured out the whole alcohol thing
first off, 술 = alcohol
조각검술 this is translated into fragment sword
rearranging 술 to 조각술검 translates it into sculpting blade
조각 is sculpture, adding 술 makes it sculpting, which probably means 술 is the suffix -ing, but because of how koreans write, it is placed at the end of the word and since the machine translators dont know to read 조각(some noun)술 as 조각술(some noun), it assumes the 술 belongs to the other noun, which is sometimes ok, but more often than not gives a bad translation, when there is a space in front of 술, it translates by itself, giving alcohol " -quote from someone that will use the tool I'm making 
I don't know how to explain it better. Hope this helps.

I guess what I'm trying to do is : replace `myword.*ex.*` with `mywordex.*.*` - I know not the best example but I guess that's what I'm trying to do. myword and ex being parameters.

Comment: It can be done, but can you please give a few examples of input and output so we understand better what you want

Comment: I must admit that your example has made me more confused than I was before. Can you show clear before/after samples? Can those characters you want to move around also occur in other places where they should *not* be moved, and if so, how can we distinguish between the two? All in all, I fear that this task (manipulating natural language) is too complex for regexes, though.

Comment: Also please try to use the code brackets { } to separate your wall of text.

Comment: It will need a good deal of knowing Korean just to know what is the question.

Comment: OK, let's take you up on `myword.*ex.*` to `mywordex.*.*`: What exactly is allowed for `.*`? Would you want to change `myword text` to `mywordex tt`? How about `myword lots and lots of words, entire paragraphs, even, and only then ex (move that too?)`? You need to be more specific in what you want to match and what you don't want to match.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps, you can split the sentence to an array. after that, you can switch the elements of the array. something like:

```
String text = "this is a text";
String[] splited = text.split(" ");
String tmp = splited[1];
splited[1] = splited[2];
splited[2] = tmp;
```

this is very simple, I don't know whether it is what you looking for or not.

Comment: This doesn't help me because I don't know in advance what are the positions of the words i want to replace.